# PXSelector on DAC field causing column filter issues

Tags: acumatica

I have a DAC which has a FK1 to Table1ID from table1 and FK2 to Table2ID from table2.  I have added a PXSelector on these fields to show the friendly name instead of the ID number.  When user filters on Table2ID and goes to add a new record on the screen and tabs from column to column to enter the information, Table1ID column value disappears.  User can add the value back to the column but I'm trying to figure out why is disappearing.  If I remove the PXSelector from the Table2ID filed everything works fine.  PXSelector is a simple select with a check for if IsActive is true.

```
   <px:PXGridColumn DataField="AdministrationRouteID" DisplayMode="Text" Width="100px" CommitChanges="True" />
   <px:PXGridColumn DataField="MedicationID" DisplayMode="Text" Width="200px" CommitChanges="True" />


    public abstract class administrationRouteID : PX.Data.IBqlField
    {
    }
    protected int? _AdministrationRouteID;
    [PXDBInt()]
    [PXDefault()]
    [PXSelector(typeof(Search<SsAhAdministrationRoute.administrationRouteID,
        Where<SsAhAdministrationRoute.isActive, Equal<True>>>), DescriptionField = typeof(SsAhAdministrationRoute.name))]
    [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Administration Route")]
    public virtual int? AdministrationRouteID
    {
        get
        {
            return this._AdministrationRouteID;
        }
        set
        {
            this._AdministrationRouteID = value;
        }
    }



    public abstract class medicationID : PX.Data.IBqlField
    {
    }
    protected int? _MedicationID;
    [PXDBInt()]
    [PXDefault()]
    [PXSelector(typeof(Search<SsAhMedication.medicationId,
        Where<SsAhMedication.isActive, Equal<True>>>), DescriptionField = typeof(SsAhMedication.name))]
    [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Medication Name")]
    public virtual int? MedicationID
    {
        get
        {
            return this._MedicationID;
        }
        set
        {
            this._MedicationID = value;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Sounds like a key error, it would help if you can post as much code (graph, dac, aspx) as possible in your answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check that CommitChanges="true" is applied only to GridColumns needing that functionality.  Try removing CommitChanges="true" from the selector columns if not needed.  SyncPosition="true" on the grid may also help, particularly when hopping from line to line during data entry.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you just need to indicate your CD field on your selector using the SubstituteKey property. The example below assume `SsAhAdministrationRoute.administrationRouteCD` is the CD user friendly value related to the `SsAhAdministrationRoute.administrationRouteID` ID key value.

```
[PXSelector(typeof(Search<SsAhAdministrationRoute.administrationRouteID,
        Where<SsAhAdministrationRoute.isActive, Equal<True>>>), 
        DescriptionField = typeof(SsAhAdministrationRoute.name),
        SubstituteKey = typeof(SsAhAdministrationRoute.administrationRouteCD))]
```